# Calculate value in column using value in previous column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table A with SKU ID's, required dates and demand and another table B with current inventory positions. For each SKU ID, the inventory from table B will be the initial value and for each required date, I want to create two new columns, beginning inventory and ending inventory, which will get calculated based on the corresponding demand. I've attached an image with the output

I found a similar thread which used CTE recursion but it only applied to one ID. Given that I have multiple ID's, i would like the code to be dynamic and realize when all records for the previous ID have been exhausted so that for the next ID, it can pull a new beginning inventory from table B

Thanks

Desired Output:
[image]

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  The later versions have better options for this kind of problem.

Comment: Hi Barry, unfortunately I'm using 2008